# UITableViewCell overflow UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I have a table in the centre of the screen in an IOS7 app, this table
has a width of 200 pixels. 
What I want is when the table enters the delete mode, and the cells gets pushed to the left, is for the cells to overflow from the table, not getting cut.
Any suggestions?